# Relative date comparsion in Mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to select all IDs, which were added in last 10 days, something like:

```
  SELECT ID FROM my_table WHERE reg_date>NOW()-10days, $link);
```

Column reg_date is in DATE format.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID FROM my_table WHERE reg_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

It's `CURDATE()`, cause with `NOW()` you include the time, so you might miss the rows that were added between midnight and the time when you execute the query.

Furthermore you were missing the `INTERVAL` keyword and it's `DAY` not `DAYS`, cause it's a unit.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT 
    `id`
FROM 
    `my_table` 
WHERE 
    DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= `reg_date` AND NOW() <= `reg_date`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM my_table WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY) <= reg_date;
```